# substition regex, with capture

Tags: regex, perl

maybe this is a stupid question but : 
i run perl 5.8.8 and i need to replace any underscore preceded by a number, with "0".

running :

```
 $var =~s /(\d)_/$10/g;
```

obviously does not work as $10 is interpreted as... well... $10, not "$1 followed by 0"

moreover, as runing perl5.8, i can't do

```
$var=~s/(?<n1>\d)\_/$+{n1}0/g;
```

any idea ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just like in various Unix shells, you can enclose the variable name in braces for disambiguation.

```
$var =~s /(\d)_/${1}0/g;
```

Or you can use a look-behind to prevent the digit from being part of the match:

```
$var =~s /(?<=\d)_/0/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

This would also be a good place for a zero width look-behind assertion:

```
$var =~ s/(?<=\d)_/0/g;
```

It looks for a digit without actually slurping the digit into the matched text.

Answer (score 0):

`$var =~s/(\d)_/${1}0/g;`

Comment: sorry, but i said i need to substitue the underscore, which imply that i keep the number before it

Answer (score 0):

Another possibilities are (not sure if applicable to perl 5.8.8)

```
s/\d\K_/0/
s/(?<=\d)_/0/
```